# Error when Restoring a backup

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, backup, restore

Why I always got this Error when Restoring a backup

"Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use"

I try this but did'nt work:

```
use Master 
ALTER DATABASE yourdatabasename SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

I always have to close the ssms and open it again to restore backup. How I will avoid  this error especially when I will use the backup/restore in my c# application? Do I have to change some properties of my database? I need this issue to resolve to avoid encountering it with the application which I am developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have any query tab connected to this specific database. If yes, you may choose another database from the dropdown instead of closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SINGLE_USER`.

```
ALTER DATABASE yourdatabasename SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```